# VBA word sub bullet points

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to figure out how to use alpha bullet points after the numeric bullet points. Specifically, I have bullets 1 through 4 with text, and then I wish to write more text on A,B,C bullets indented underneath number 4, and then continue typing on number 5,6 etc. This is done in vba to generate word documents. The information on these lines is static and does not change. I'm also curious as what listtemplate type gets me arrow formatted bullets.

```
ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(2).Name = ""
 .Selection.range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate       ListTemplate:=.ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(2), _
    defaultlistbehavior:=wdWord3ListBehavior
```

[image]
         .

Comment: record a macro if you doing the bullets, then examine the resulting code

Comment: I have recorded a larger macro, but the section that produces the bullets is cited above. I'm not quite sure how to reference sub bullets, however.

Comment: what do you mean by "reference sub bullets" ?  i posted some code, but, somehow, i think that you are asking for something else.  the code, that you posted, applies a specific list template to the text. it does not define the template itself.

Comment: Yea, not 100% sure either. I'm just trying to indent to create the alpha bullet list within the other numeric bullet lists. Does your code do that?

Comment: This is sort of related, but do you know what wd listnumber gets you arrow formated bullets?

Comment: i think that i am misunderstanding what it is that you are trying to do. please describe what you are trying to do ... starting with blank page in ms word, what steps are needed to achieve the finished document?  why is VBA used in the process?

Answer (score 0):

do you actually have to do it programmatically? you can define a new multilevel list in the paragraph tab.

here is an excerpt from a recorded macro where i changed the level1 bullet to number and level2 bullet to alpha

the recorded macro had 9 levels of bullets

it is possible that this is your answer:

```
ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2).NumberFormat = "%2"
```

recorded code is below

```
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "%1"
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .ResetOnHigher = 0
    .StartAt = 1
    With .Font
        .Bold = wdUndefined
        .Italic = wdUndefined
        .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
        .Subscript = wdUndefined
        .Superscript = wdUndefined
        .Shadow = wdUndefined
        .Outline = wdUndefined
        .Emboss = wdUndefined
        .Engrave = wdUndefined
        .AllCaps = wdUndefined
        .Hidden = wdUndefined
        .Underline = wdUndefined
        .Color = wdUndefined
        .Size = wdUndefined
        .Animation = wdUndefined
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
        .Name = ""
    End With
    .LinkedStyle = ""
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
    .NumberFormat = "%2"
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleUppercaseLetter
    .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .ResetOnHigher = 1
    .StartAt = 1
    With .Font
        .Bold = wdUndefined
        .Italic = wdUndefined
        .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
        .Subscript = wdUndefined
        .Superscript = wdUndefined
        .Shadow = wdUndefined
        .Outline = wdUndefined
        .Emboss = wdUndefined
        .Engrave = wdUndefined
        .AllCaps = wdUndefined
        .Hidden = wdUndefined
        .Underline = wdUndefined
        .Color = wdUndefined
        .Size = wdUndefined
        .Animation = wdUndefined
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
        .Name = ""
    End With
    .LinkedStyle = ""
End With
```